# CodeWars - Sum of odd Numbers - For loop

Tags: java, for-loop

I have attempted to make a piece of code that accepts an input of "n", calculates the sum of the numbers on the nth line an odd number triangle, which looks like:

```
             1
          3     5
       7     9    11
   13    15    17    19
21    23    25    27    29
```

etc. So for `n = 3`, the sum would be `7 + 9 + 11` ie `27`

I know that n is not only the line number but also equals the number of numbers on that line. so `n = 3` also have 3 odd numbers on it. Therefore I thought that I could get the first number of the line, then just loop through adding two to the previous number then sum it.

My code below doesn't work, so for an input of `n=43`, my code calculates that the sum is `3570` whereas it actually equals `79507`.

```
public static int rowSumOddNumbers(int n) {
    int firstNum = (2 * n) - 1;
    int total = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        total += (firstNum + 2);
    }
    return total;
}
```

I believe my problem is that I'm not adding the previous number together with the current number + 2. Should it be that I need to store the previous loop's outcome than add it to the current loop's outcome?

Any help appreciated.

Comment: What made you come up with `(2 * n) - 1` for `firstNum`? It's clearly wrong.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Mathematically, the sum of the n<sup>th</sup> line of odd numbers is n<sup>3</sup>, so this gives the correct result:

```
int rowSumOddNumbers(int n) {
    return n * n * n;
}
```

I leave the derivation to the reader...

Answer (score 6):

This is how you can approach the problem there may other faster methods also.First you have to find the first number in the nth line.You can see that the starting numbers of every line are in a sequence (arithmetic progress - AP)

```
1 3 7 13 21 ...
```

therefore nth term will be `(n-1)^2 + (n-1)+1`

Once you find that,you can find the sum of all the digits in that line
by iterating from that number to the number of terms in the line

```
for(int i=0;i<n;i+=2)
{
    sum+=(Nth_Term+i);
}
```

or simply just apply the formula of the sum of n-terms of AP with comman ratio 2

```
sum= n*( 2*Nth_Term + (n-1)*2)/2 ;
```

Further if you will put the value of Nth term in the above formula you will find that it evaluates to `n^3.`

```
sum = n*( 2* ((n-1)^2 + (n-1)+1) + (n-1)*2)/2 = n^3
```

Answer (score 1):

for javascript this would be simply

```
Math.pow(n,3)
```

Comment: dont forget to use return

Answer (score 1):

```
int rowSumOddNumbers(int n) {
  var odd = [];
  var starts = (n * n) - (n - 1);

  while(n > 0){
    odd.add(starts);
    starts += 2;
    n--;
  }

  int sum = odd.reduce((value, element) => value + element);
  print(sum);
  return sum;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what you are looking for.

```
public class RowSumOddNumbers {

    public static int array[] = {1, 3, 5, 7, 9, 11, 13, 15, 17, 19};

    public static int rowSumOddNumbers(int n) {
        int firstIndex = 0;
        for (int i = 1; i < n; i++) {
            firstIndex += i;
        }
        int total = 0;
        for (int i = firstIndex; i < firstIndex + n; i++) {
            total += array[i];
        }
        return total;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(RowSumOddNumbers.rowSumOddNumbers(3)); //27
        System.out.println(RowSumOddNumbers.rowSumOddNumbers(1)); //1
        System.out.println(RowSumOddNumbers.rowSumOddNumbers(2)); //8
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For PHP:

```
function rowSumOddNumbers($n) {
  return pow($n, 3);
}
```

Comment: Hi, and welcome to SO.  While we thank you for this answer, note that the question is asking about Java (you can see the tags), not PHP.